# Unexpected behavior of spark.sql in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

I'm observing weird behavior in pyspark 3.0.1
I have a data frame abc contains id,group & date. The sample data looks like

```
ID      Group      Date
11A      5         2019-12-10
12A      4         2019-06-11
12A      4         2019-09-08
10A      5         2019-12-08
9C       3         2019-06-04
```

printSchema() is retuning

```
ID: string (nullable = true)
Group: string (nullable = true) 
Date: date (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to group the data by ID to get maximum date by ID. So I wrote following query

```
abc.registerTempTable("abc")
abc_maxDate=spark.sql("select ID,max(Date) as LATEST_Date from abc where Date is not NULL group by Id")
```

But while I'm trying to view the result then I'm not seeing the data for `11A`. Even if I'm trying to run following query

```
check=spark.sql("select ID,Date from abc where ID='11A")
```

is also not returning any result. But following query is returning result

```
check1=spark.sql("select * from abc where ID='11A")
```

Did any of you face similar problem? Can you able to suggest me what could be the probable reason for such issue?

Comment: Of course `check` cannot return any results. `Latest_Date` does not exist in the table `abc`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's not `Latest_date`,it's `Date`. Corrected it

Comment: Your edited code works for me. You're probably missing something else...

Comment: @mck, I have given it using dummy data. My actual data size is around 500K records.I'm looking for some suggestion to find out the probable cause for this issue. I'm new to pyspark. So I posted it here so that expert like you can suggest me where should I look to rectify the issue

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much that I can do except guessing